# Azure blob storage returns Unauthorized with SAS generated URL

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to generate a URL where users can access a file that is in a blob storage container on Azure. The blob storage container is heavily restricted by IP address, and then the service I'm building will manage requests and generate a URL where users can access the file directly. Here is the code used to generate the URL (I think the code itself is probably fine).

```
CloudBlobContainer container = BlobStorage.GetContainer(_accountStatementEmailConfig.BlobStorageContainerName);
CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(document.StoragePath);

if (!blob.Exists())
{
    return NotFound();
}

TimeSpan sasExpiryTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(_apiConfig.PresignedURLExpiryInMinutes);

SharedAccessBlobPermissions permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read;

string sasToken = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy
{
    Permissions = permissions,
    SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(sasExpiryTime)
}, new SharedAccessBlobHeaders(), _apiConfig.SharedAccessSignaturePermissionsPolicyName);

string documentUrl = $"{blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri}{sasToken}";
```

The code generates the URL fine, but when a user goes to the URL they receive the following error:

```
<Error>
    <Code>AuthorizationFailure</Code>
    <Message>
        This request is not authorized to perform this operation. RequestId:92d7ca35-501e-0016-2a65-973659000000 Time:2023-06-01T08:43:35.2439678Z
    </Message>
</Error>
```

It was perhaps my incorrect assumption about SAS that the token would allow me to bypass the IP restrictions since I am generating the URL from a whitelisted IP. Am I taking the incorrect approach, or is there something minor I am overlooking?

Comment: Are you using the SAS URL from a whitelisted IP address?

Comment: No, my understanding was that the SAS URL could be accessed from anywhere, similar to how a presigned URL in AWS works. I'm guessing that was an incorrect assumption? If so, do you know how I might manage it so that the URL can only be generated from a specific IP, but the URLs generated can then be accessed by anyone?

Comment: It is not possible because the IP restrictions you have put in place will prevent the access to the storage account. The request must be made from the white listed IP addresses only.

Comment: Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do then? I don't want anybody to be able to access a particular file unless a URL has been generated via SAS. Perhaps coming from AWS is clouding my understanding of how things should work, but I don't want to have my container open to the public, but I do want to be able to generate some temporary URLs where they can be accessed from the public.

Comment: You would need to remove the IP address restrictions so that authorized users will be able to access the storage account from anywhere. That way when you create SAS URL, your users will be able to access the storage contents from anywhere.

Comment: Okay, but wouldn't that pose a serious security risk? I don't want the container to be publicly accessible without an SAS token, would removing the IP restrictions allow individuals to access the files in my container without one? I know in AWS if you don't lock down by IP then anyone can access any file at any time. I don't want that happening here.

Comment: No, you don't have to keep container public. The container should be private so that a user needs some kind of [authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-requests-to-azure-storage) to access the storage account.

Comment: Aha, cheers Gaurav, that makes a lot of sense. A bit confusing since AWS does things a fair bit different. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gaurav Mantri pointed out in comments, the issue is my understanding of how Azure handles permissions since all of my previous experience is from AWS.

In Azure the storage account and the containers have separate access levels. Can achieve similar functionality to AWS's private + presignedURL option by setting the Storage Account to public, and each of the individual containers to private. Then using the generated SAS URL to access the file.